# How to pause AFTER user input is registered in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have created an Rmarkdown document that will dynamically generate some tables based on user output. Some of the filters users can interact with can take multiple options. This can create a lot of lag as the table constantly updates when the user changes a single parameter even if they are not finished updated the settings.

Consider the following inputs:

```
selectInput("range_1", label = "Sex:",
             choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), multiple = TRUE, selected = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

selectInput("range_2", label = "Product:",
             choices = c("a", "b", "c"), multiple = TRUE, selected = c("a","b", "c"))

renderPrint(f(input$range_1, input$range_1))
```

A table will be generated based on range_1, and range_2. The default range for range_1 includes all options, so if a user wants to only filter on "1" they need to deselect 5 4 3 2. They only want to see one new table, but the dynamically generated table will calculate it several times (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3), (1,2), and then finally (1). This calculation is a little slow so there is a lot of lag time. The opposite problem occurs if the default select is "1" or empty and the user wants to select all options.

The intended behavior would for there to be some sort of pause after a change is made in the user inputs so if any other change is made shortly after the table will just refresh once.

Comment: The easier solution is to add a validation button. Maybe you can use invalidateLater combined with an observe of all your inputs, if time of last change > treshold, you evaluate otherwise you reset the timer. Hope it helps

Comment: Just as @Clemsang mentions, I'd go with a update button. An alternative would be to [debounce](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/debounce.html) your inputs.